# не могу найти пример запуска класса spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, mvc

Нужен пример для очень начинающего, как сделать с помощью спринга форму так что бы в вебе была одна форма с кнопкой которая просто по нажатию запускает запускает работу метода, просто кнопка старт.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, с чем именно возникают проблемы?

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring_ru.html пошаговая инструкция. Вам нужно создать в jsp файле форму, которая будет отсылать запрос на один из контроллеров Spring'а. А в обработчике запроса Вы и запустите тот метод, который пожелаете.

Comment: @KirillStoianov в том что после обычной джавы в спринг сложно смортреть и пользовать и в том что не знаю англ языка) я нашёл пару примеров вроде http://javastudy.ru/spring-mvc/hello-world-example/ но тут идёт передача значения а я ничего не хочу передавать мне надо просто добавить к имеющему коду веб морду что бы нажать на кнопку и запустился метод run() без каких либо лишних классов и передач данных.

Answer (score 3):

На сайте [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) очень подробно по шагам расписано, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Предельно простой maven-проект для предельно простого примера обработки формы с помощью Spring MVC

**\pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-simple-form</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring MVC Simple Form</name>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin> <!-- Для простого тестирования -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.11.v20160721</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Simple Form</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**\src\main\java\com\example\SimpleFormController.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class SimpleFormController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm() {
        return "form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleForm(@RequestParam("name") String name, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "form";
    }
}
```

**\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp\form.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>

        <c:if test="${not empty name}">
        <hr>
        <h3>Привет, ${name}!</h2>
        </c:if>
    </body>
</html>
```

Выполняете из корня проекта команду `mvn jetty:run` и можете переходить в браузере по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello

Comment: а как к этому всему подключить имеющийся контекст? просто оч новичёк в спринге прям совсем. Есть сейчас написанный aplication context который в майне берется с помощью FileSystemXmlApplicationContext

Comment: @Ilya, для новичка важен системный подход в усвоении знаний. Чтобы бардак в голове не образовался. Тем более, что Spring - не та область знаний, которую можно объяснить на пальцах. Рекомендую приобрести книгу Крейга Уоллса "Spring в действии", неспеша её читать и эксперементировать с примерами.